# Which of the following two ways of using C structs in a for loop is preferred?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Let's say that we want do some operations in a for loop involving a struct. This struct will contain an element which is a pointer to char. So something of the following form:

```
struct foo
{
    char *s;    
}foo;

struct foo *new_foo(){
    struct foo *myfoo = malloc(sizeof(foo));
    myfoo->s = NULL;
    
    return myfoo;
}

void free_foo(struct foo *myfoo){
    free(myfoo->s);
}
```

The basic structure of the for loop is that given some variables (which depend on the loop index) it computes something and returns the information about foo (then this may be directed to some output or used for other calculations but I wont get into details of that). There are two ways of achieving such an effect, one is via a function that returns struct foo and the other struct foo *. To demonstrate an example (though a stupid one), these could be:

```
struct foo foo_fun1(int size)
{
    int i;
    struct foo myfoo;
    myfoo.s = calloc(size+1, sizeof(char));
    
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
        myfoo.s[i] = 'A';
    }
    
    return myfoo;
    
}

struct foo *foo_fun2(int size)
{
    int i;
    struct foo *myfoo = new_foo();
    myfoo->s = calloc(size+1, sizeof(char));
    
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
        myfoo->s[i] = 'A';
    }
    
    return myfoo;
    
}
```

They achieve the same effect without any leaks if used as such:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    
    struct foo myfoo1;
    struct foo *myfoo2 = NULL;
    
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        
        myfoo1 = foo_fun1(i);
        myfoo2 = foo_fun2(i);
        
        free_foo(&myfoo1);
        free_foo(myfoo2);
        free(myfoo2);
        
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the more realistic scenario this for loop would be going for possibly couple million times (not with these functions though!) and the created structs could contain multiple different strings of lengths that could be as much as couple hundred chars. My question is style or efficiency wise would one consider one method over the other?

Comment: Apple Clang 11 compiles the loop in both of them to `memset`. The one calling `new_foo` has an additional `malloc`, so it will take more time. The `calloc` is wasteful in both of them, as all but the last byte are overwritten anyway, so it is preferable to call `malloc` and write one null byte at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which of the following two ways of using C structs in a for loop is preferred? [sic]

Evidently, there are two contrasting alternatives you want to consider:

> one is via a function that returns struct foo and the other struct foo *.

Important characteristics of returning a `struct foo` include:

- The called function does not incur the cost of allocating space for the structure.
- The structure is copied from called function to the caller.  This copying may be costly if the structure is large, but it is pretty cheap if the structure is small.
- The caller does not acquire a duty to free the structure itself (though it may acquire a duty to free its contents, as in the example)
- The lifetime of the object, if any, in which the caller stores the structure data is controlled by the caller.

Important characteristics of returning a `struct foo *` include:

- The called function (probably) incurs the cost of allocating space for the structure.
- Only a pointer to the structure is copied back to the caller.  This is pretty cheap regardless of the size of the structure.
- Presuming that the pointed-to structure is dynamically allocated, as in the example, the caller does acquire a duty to free the structure itself, in addition to any duty it may acquire to free the contents.
- The lifetime of the object in which the structure is stored is controlled by the called function (and presumably it is "allocated" duration, though it does not have to be).

> My question is style or efficiency wise would one consider one method over the other?

Supposing that the example driver code reflects the intended usage, in that the structure objects are not required to live past the end of the loop-body execution in which they are created, I would be inclined to save the cost of allocating and deallocating many `struct foo` objects, as dynamic memory allocation is relatively expensive.  If `struct foo` is small, then that would mean your first alternative, returning a `struct foo`.  But if `struct foo` were large, then I would consider using an *initialization* function instead of an object-creation function:

```
void foo_fun3(struct foo *the_foo, int size) {
    char *s = malloc(size + 1);

    if (s) {
        memset(s, 'A', size);
        s[size] = '\0';
    }
    
    the_foo->s = s;  
}

// ...

// usage:
void f(void) {
    struct foo a_foo;
    struct foo *a_foo_pointer = malloc(sizeof(*a_foo_pointer));

    foo_fun3(&a_foo, A_SIZE);
    foo_fun3(a_foo_pointer, A_SIZE);

    // ...
}
```

This approach has the advantage that the caller controls whether memory allocation for the overall structure is performed, and it avoids the cost of copying a result back from called function to caller.

All three are fine stylistically, according to me, though the structure-return alternative is less used than the other two in my experience.  As far as efficiency goes, I'm inclined to think that avoiding dynamic allocation as much as is reasonably possible is likely to be to your advantage performance-wise, but you should always answer performance questions by *testing*.

And speaking of avoiding dynamic allocation, you should consider whether you can avoid allocating the structure *member*(s), too.  You indeed should be able to do that in the example code if you can place an upper bound on the size of the internal buffer, but there may be additional considerations in a real-world scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your points. However I do not have much of a intution about what is considered a large struct. In my case my structs would be containing two strings of length ~300. Would that be considered large? As for the last point, I guess I could define it via a macro to cover most cases and those interested in more particular applications could recompile it with the correct flags. Would that be reasonable?

Comment: @Sina, your example struct contains one *pointer*, not a string of any length.  The size of a pointer is independent of the size of the data to which it points.  I would consider two pointers to still be pretty small, but two arrays of length 300 to be fairly large.  Again, however, where relative performance of two or more alternatives matters, you should *test* to see which performs better.

Comment: The code above is a simplified version of my use case. In my use case, when the struct foo is initialized, it will be containing two pointers to char arrays of about length 300 in my use cases. But in any case your third alternative makes this concern invalid since one is always passing pointers to the function and not returning any values.